SQLite database Table not found
I'm doing laravel project, and trying to create a database factories and migration, where i want to put random data.
I'm using PHP artisan tinker to generate random data for the database.
But I get error message :

It sounds the SQLite cannot find the categories table in the main schema.
But i'm pretty sure i got the path where my database located right.
I try to clean my cache using
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear

and it didn't give any changed.
I'm expect i could find where did it get me wrong

Did you run php artisan migrate for creating your table in the database?

Check your Categories Model...it's probably missing or incorrect naming structures
